# Counting duplicate lines based on user input without showing certain information

Tags: shell, grep

Hi i got this short code that i want to use to count the number of duplicate lines but i only wish for the number to be shown

the input of the file

```
 The Hunger Games:Suzanne Collins:1:1:1
 The Hunger Games:test:1:1:1
```

desired output

```
 found: 2
```

the output with the code below

```
 found: 2 The Hunger Games
```

Code that was used

```
 echo "Title: "
 read title
 record=$(grep -io "$title" BookDB.txt | sort | uniq -c)
 echo "found: " $record
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` or `cut`

**Awk**

```
 echo "found: " $record | awk '{print $1  $2}'
```

**Cut**

```
 echo "found: 2 The Hunger Games" | cut -f1-2 -d" "
```

**Test**

```
$ echo "found: " $record | awk '{print $1  $2}'
found: 2
$ echo "found: 2 The Hunger Games" | cut -f1-2 -d" "
found: 2
```

Comment: omg it works perfectly. i like to ask why the awk command use '{print $1 $2}'? im curious to know why it is used like this cause usually isn't it suppose to print the field?

Comment: `print $1` will print the first field, `found:` and `print $2` will print the second field ie `2`